# How to find the executable generated by a bazel target

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to `bazel run //foo` without getting all the INFO lines that are output during the build step. [this github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4867) tracks this feature request, but it has not been implemented yet. To make this work and be platform independent I have been trying to find a `bazel query/aquery/cquery` command that tells me the executable generated by a bazel target (basically whatever `bazel run //foo` would have ran).

My work around has been to write a bash script that calls `buildout=$(bazel build //$target --color=yes 2>&1)` and then runs the executable directly if the build command exited successfully. I have been pouring over the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/query-how-to.html) for the various query commands, but haven't been able to find a general way to do this. The closest I've gotten is running a regex on the output of `bazel aquery //foo` to look for the output line.

Is there a better tool for this job or a specific query command that will tell me this?

Thanks!

Comment: After the build, your executables will be in the bazel-bin directory.  Would running the executable directly from there work? For example, in bash $ ./bazel-bin/foo

Comment: so where it is exactly is platform dependent unfortunately. on my machine it's bazel-bin/foo/bar/tool/linux_amd64_stripped/tool and on mac it's darwin_amd64_stripped. The current version of my script does almost exactly as you described, and I could adjust it to try and search for the right system-dependent folder, but i was really hoping there would be an easy, concise to identify it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `cquery` and `--starlark:expr`.

```sh
bazel cquery --output=starlark --starlark:expr=target.files_to_run.executable.path //foo
```

That prints to stdout the executable's path, relative to the execution root, e.g.

```
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo
```

(Note that `bazel-bin` is simply a convenience symlink to the `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin` directory, depending on the target configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering your question but fixing your original problem:

```
bazel run --experimental_ui_limit_console_output=1 //:hello
```

As to your question the location of a binary (as long as you're not customising the toolchain will be dependant on the name of the target.

So `//:hello` will end up in `bazel-bin/hello`, `//a/long:hello` will end up in `bazel-bin/a/long/hello` and so on and so forth ...

Comment: my concern is the docs say this will limit the console output to one byte, so if you were to `bazel run --experimental_ui_limit_console_output=1 //:hello > some_file.txt` it'll have an extra character at the beginning. afaik this is usually a new line, but I don't think that's guaranteed.